# Wordpress Comment box translation

Tags: wordpress, string, translate

My Wordpress website is in 4 languages. I have already translated my Wordpress theme string in all languages through Loco translate. But the strings which i have attached in screenshots were not include in the string translate file(PO file). Can you please tell me How i can translate my comment portion all 4 languages?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add the strings that aren't translated to the appropriate text domain using the function [_e()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/), read more in the [codex link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/). When you added them as needed you will see them shows in Loco.

Comment: But if will add the strings which i want to translate in this function. This will only translate for only one language and my translation will show in all other language too. But i want to change these string with respect to different languages.

Comment: Once you add them in the text domain Loco will recognize them and let you translate them in your 4 languages

Comment: ' _e('Leave a Reply', '
Hinterlasse eine Antwort'); ' Where i should add this code in my wordpress?

Comment: On the page that the form is included, i need more infos to be helpful but i don't think this is the correct place to discuss it anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you can show these comments/string translated by third party API on the frontend, like Google Translate. you can find the [Google Translate API](https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api).
For more information, you can see usage here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api

**Note:** This is custom coding if you are a developer you can move ahead. Also, this is not like WPML like the plugin, but a lightweight option in WordPress to do it easily. You can try it, so you don't need to translate every time each comment in four languages.

Comment: No i can't use Google translate because its a client website. My client doesnot want google translate. I will do custom code but i want little guidance.

Comment: I'm not recommended to add Google Translate on the whole site, but you can use this jQuery API for comment loop and show the translated string on comment listing. That's it if your other option doesn't work!